# Definition of Ramsey ultrafilter

Tags: set-theory

We say that an ultrafilter $\mathcal{U}$ of $\omega$ is a Ramsey ultrafilter, if for each $c:[\omega]^2 \rightarrow 2$, there exists $H \in \mathcal{U}$ such that $c|[H]^2$ is costant. My question is, since $c$ is costant in $[H]^2$ for each subset $H$ of cardinality 2, we assume into the definition that $|H| \geq 3$?

Comment: One normally requires Ramsey ultrafilters to be **non-principal** ultrafilters with that property.

Comment: Yes, but with this definition, it follows that the ultrafilter is not principal, it is right?

Comment: No, it doesn’t. By that definition a principal ultrafilter on $\omega$ is trivially Ramsey.

Comment: Even if we assume that $|H| \geq 3$?

Comment: Sorry, you’re right: I was splitting my attention between this and another obligation and lost track. Yes, if you require that $|H|\ge 3$, you can find a ‘bad’ coloring. That’s a completely artificial restriction, however.

Comment: Thank you, I have to solve an exercice that from this definition I have to prove that an ulltrafilter of Ramsey is not principal, but into the definition missing the hypothesis that $|H| \geq 3$.